# Need suggestion on database design structure design for a ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, database-design, asp.net-mvc-2

i am trying to learn ASP.Net MVC2/3 and trying to work on a web project that will actually be a blogging project. So i would have the similar structure as a normal blog looks like. I would have title, blog entry, some tags and other stuff. Now i want suggestion on using database. Since the blog entry i.e. an article would be a text with multiple paragraphs and might also contain some images. So i was wondering what kind of database should be good to store these texts. I can use SQL for storing text but not sure if it would be fast enough. Any suggestions on where can i get or i should say learn about good database design for such application.

Also it would be helpful if anyone can suggest a good source for ASP.net MVC3 learning. I can look online for tutorials, but some good books for beginners would be helpful.

Any suggestion would be great.

Thanks. :)

Comment: My suggestion to you is to read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: download some open source blogging software and see how they works

Comment: There is already one such example available on MSDN site ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

download sqlExpress from Microsoft, it will be plenty fast enough to store/retrieve text, it's free and it works well with .net

I think the easiest way to store the posts would be to store the text as HTML, with  tags that point to somewhere in your file structure. When you add an image, you upload it to that directory, and generate a link for it.

Take a look at how wordpress works, that should give you plenty of ideas for writing your own code.